Creating custom variants with Material UI give warning
Creating custom variants with Material UI give warning Failed prop type: Invalid prop variant of value contained-primary supplied to Button, expected one of ["contained","outlined","text",null].enter image description here
Can anyone suggest How to handle this warning?
I have already create them and passed to to Application
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "Inter",
  },
  box: {
    fontFamily: "Inter",
  },
  tabs: {
    fontFamily: "Inter",
  },
  tab: {
    fontFamily: "Inter",
  },
  components: {
    MuiButtonBase: {
      defaultProps: {
        disableRipple: true,
      },
    },
    MuiButton: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: "text" },
          style: {
            color: "#041433",
            fontSize: "16px",
            borderRadius: 0,
            textTransform: "capitalize",
            "&:hover": {
              color: "#0066F9",
            },
          },
        },
        {
          props: { variant: "contained-primary" },
          style: {
            color: "#ffffff",
            backgroundColor: "#0066F9",
            fontSize: "15px",
            boxShadow: "none",
            borderRadius: "0px",
            textTransform: "capitalize",
            fontWeight: 700,
            letterSpacing: "0.2px",
            padding: "8px 25px",
            "&:hover": {
              background: "#0066F9",
              color: "#fff",
              opacity: "0.8",
            },
          },
        },
        {
          props: { variant: "contained-white" },
          style: {
            color: "#041433",
            backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
            border: "1px solid #d7d7d7",
            fontSize: "15px",
            boxShadow: "none",
            borderRadius: "0px",
            textTransform: "capitalize",
            fontWeight: 700,
            letterSpacing: "0.2px",
            padding: "8px 25px",
            "&:hover": {
              opacity: "0.8",
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});



const root = document.getElementById("root");
createRoot(root).render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <App />
  </ThemeProvider>
);

I want to get rid of this warning.
